# Clion using previous version of file for debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

When I try to make a simple one line change to my C++ code and try debugging it Clion always opens another tab with the full path listed to the same file, but it is the previous version that doesn't have my new edit.

I have tried doing save all, clean, and rebuild.  But it seems to not update the files for debugging.  Even restarting CLion doesn't seem to help

Is it a CLion bug? Or is there something else I need to do to update these files?

Edit: The changes show up in the file when I search for the file in the file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using one file for editing and another file for compiling.

Maybe it is an issue caused by how you created your project (did you select "import project from sources..." if the code was already written?).

I recommend you make some change to your file, and then with the Explorer/Finder go and see the file yo think should be modified to validate your changes.